# Beginning to write a novel?

Tags: novel

I already wrote the girl's (Ali) chapter and I'm very pleased with it as I've been trying a lot of different things for about two years now and when I start the boy's (Gunner) chapter I can't figure out how to make it interesting. It's a love story, but they haven't met yet. Ali has just gotten into a terrible car accident and her brother drops everything to get her at the hospital when he finds out. Gunner is her brother's best friend, and he knows of Ali but hasn't met her yet because they're in college while she just finished high school and her brother is over-protective of her and doesn't want any of his friends around her. I want Gunner's chapter to start when Matt rushes out to get Ali, but Matt doesn't explain where he's going or why he's so worried, but the reader will know because Ali's chapter comes first. Is there any advice anyone can give me on how to start this? Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking abut what to write are off-topic here, I'm closing this for now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't find the boy's perspective interesting?

How did you approach writing the girl's chapter? Approach the boy's chapter the same. There must be something to interest you. If there isn't, maybe it is better if you write the whole book from the girl's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Give Gunner a problem to deal with. Let him try to solve it. But arrange for him to fail, and for things to get worse instead of better.

That's called a try/fail cycle. Try/fail cycles are standard elements of much fiction.